# Pub Build by Command Line

Tags: build, dart, dart2js

How to use *pub build* by command line directly from terminal? Using *dart2js* is easy, it works like this:

/Applications/dart-sdk/bin/dart2js --minify --out=file:/Users/muggins/my_project/web/my_project.dart.js /Users/muggins/my_project/web/my_project.dart

But this creates the *my_project.dart.js* file into the same directory as *my_project.dart*. How can I obtain the distinct directory *build* by command line without using a software like ItelliJ IDEA?

I can't get any result from https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/cmd/pub-build.html.

Comment: What's the problem with `pub build` from command line? Do you use a directory structure like explained in https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html with `index.html` in the `web` sub-directory?

Comment: Yes I do, but the terminal says: Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/Users/muggins". And the file exists!

Comment: and you run `pub build` from the directory that contains `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: I tried again and again but bummer!